# find out if trigonometric is been used and track symbol variable

Tags: python, sympy

I will have data which uses degrees for the trigonometric functions.

I will use sympy and since it uses radians for the trigonometric functions, I want to be able to convert and use degrees.

But, I will not know which symbol variable is been used as input to the trigonometric function.

So , I will have something like:

```
import sympy
from sympy import mpmath

a = 2
b = 30
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
expr = 'sqrt(a + cos(b))'
expres = sympy.sympify(expr)

print(expres.atoms(sympy.cos))
```

The `b` is `30` and it is in degrees (so, in the `cos(b)` computations it must be degrees, not radians as sympy expects).

But, as I said, another time the program runs, it will use another symbol variable for trigonometric.Or, more than one trigonometric functions.

I thought if using `atoms` in order to find if in the expression I have trigonometric functions.And then , somehow , use degrees instead of radians wherever the corresponding symbol variables is been used.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably the most clean way to avoid this problem is to tell `sympify` to use custom definitions for selected symbols/strings, e.g., like this:

```
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import sin, pi, Lambda, sympify

sin_degree = Lambda(x, sin(x*pi/180))
degree_trigs = {"sin": sin_degree}

expr_string = "sin(a) + sin(b**d + exp(c))"
expr = sympify(expr_string, locals=degree_trigs)
print(expr)
```

This returns:

```
sin(pi*a/180) + sin(pi*(b**d/180 + exp(c)/180))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subs` with functions, e.g., like this:

```
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import sin, exp, pi, Lambda

sin_degree = Lambda(x, sin(x*pi/180))

expr = sin(a) + sin(b**d + exp(c))
print( expr.subs(sin,sin_degree) )
```

This returns:

```
sin(pi*a/180) + sin(pi*(b**d/180 + exp(c)/180))
```